# php zipArchive->close() returns False

Tags: php, zip

I have a function which creates a zip file.

```
function zipDoc($docRoot,$archiveName,$testsFolder){
$filename = tempnam($testsFolder, "doc");
$cwd=getcwd();
chdir ($docRoot);


 if (is_writeable($docRoot)){
    echo $docRoot." is writeable";
  }
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
        exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
    }
  echo "<br/>";
  if (is_writeable(dirname($filename))){
    echo dirname($filename)." is writeable";
  }
    $folders = array ("_rels","docProps","word");
    // initialize an iterator
    // pass it the directory to be processed
    foreach ($folders as $folder){
        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new    RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder."/"));
        // iterate over the directory
        // add each file found to the archive
        foreach ($iterator as $key=>$value) {
      if (!is_readable($key)){
           echo  "File ".$key." not readeble";
      }
            $zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");
        }
    }
    $zip->addFile("[Content_Types].xml");

    // close and save archive
    echo "<br/>";
  if ($zip->close()){
  echo $filename." is Closed";
  }
  else{
  echo $filename." is not closed";
  }
    $newname=str_replace(".tmp",".docx",$filename);
    rename($filename,$newname);
    chdir($cwd);
    return $newname;
}
```

The output is that both folders are writeable (I checked that on filesystem as well), and that the zip file is not closed!!!
Any suggestions, why is it not closing?
Edit: Status of file after close() method call is 3670068, function rename says that file is being used by another process. The file is created but has 0kb.

Comment: What about errors, warning messages etc?

Comment: Is your SafeZipArchive based on ZipArchive? If yes - take a look at [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php#108601) page. I see it has status property. Do you have it?

Comment: Where did you get `SafeZipArchive` ???

Comment: It is just a wrapper of ZipArchive. allowed me to check whether all files exist...I just edited the code to use ZipArchive again

Comment: @FAngel:do you mean calling that function with a zip file?

Comment: @MartinM - I mean that if you have a status property in your $zip object and SafeZipArchive is based on ZipArchive class available in PHP (looks like it is a part of PHP extension, but anyway) you can check that status property. That function is just to translate status code into human readable form. It is up to you if you want to run it or will just get a code and see what it means by reading that function personaly

Comment: Sorry I was a bit confused at first, anyway, after calling this function right after adding last file->N No Error, after close() -> uknown status 3670068

Comment: This looks little strange: `$zip->addFile("[Content_Types].xml")` try it with `or die ("ERROR: Could not add file")` And if it is not added- try renaming that file name

Comment: @FAngel this is not the issue, script is still working, unknown status seems to happen right after calling close() method. Script works fine on localhost on other machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found a solution:
When adding files from folders to a zip-file I missed to check if it is a real file, or just a link to current or parent folder eg.: /. or /..
After adding this simple check when iterating files, everything works fine.

```
if (substr($key,-1)=="."){
                continue;
            }
```

Hope somebody will use this.